# Add 'active' class to same href as current clicked menu link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this menu structure:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
 <li><a class="menu-link" href="#day">Day</a></li>
 <li><a class="menu-link" href="#night">Night</a></li>
 <li><a class="menu-link" href="#drinks">Joogid</a></li>
 <li><a class="menu-link" href="#takeaway">Takeaway</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to add active class to a tab if the same href in the menu is clicked, i.e :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" role="tablist">
         <li class="nav-item active">
             <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#day" role="tab">DAY</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#night" role="tab">NIGHT</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#drinks" role="tab">JOOGID<br></a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#takeaway" role="tab">takeaway</a>
         </li>
</ul>
```

I'm working with this code, but it doesn't seem to be close what I'm trying to acheive:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $anchors = $('.menu-link'),
    $items = $('.nav-link);

    $anchors.on('click', function() {
        var selectedIndex = $anchors.index(this);

        $anchors.removeClass('active').eq(selectedIndex).addClass('active');
        $items.removeClass('active').eq(selectedIndex).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

How would one add active class to tab and remove it from all other with click on the same href link click in the dropdown menu?

Any advice appreciated

Comment: You code seems to work, but you have a type error `$('.nav-link)` its missing the `'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the click trigger , and its going to perform the default behaviour (change tab class , and make tab active ) so you code should be like :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $anchors = $('.menu-link'),
    $items = $('.nav-link');

    $anchors.on('click', function() {
        var selectedIndex = $(this).attr('href');
        $items.eq(selectedIndex).find('a').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

see beleow snippet :

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $anchors = $('.menu-link'),
      $items = $('.nav-item');

  $anchors.on('click', function() {
    var selectedIndex = $anchors.index(this);
    $items.eq(selectedIndex).find('a').trigger('click');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
    <li><a class="menu-link" href="#day">Day</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu-link" href="#night">Night</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu-link" href="#drinks">Joogid</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu-link" href="#takeaway">Takeaway</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><br><br><br><br>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#day" role="tab">DAY</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#night" role="tab">NIGHT</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#drinks" role="tab">JOOGID<br></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#takeaway" role="tab">takeaway</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="day" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>Tab 1</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="night" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Tab 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="drinks" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Tab 3</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="takeaway" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Tab 3</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my pleasure :)  .

Comment: Hi, forgot totally about the tab panels that should also have the active class. Would you any advice to modify it accordingly?

The html is for the tabs: <div class="tab-pane active" id="takeaway" role="tabpanel">

Comment: hey @user3615851 see my improved edited answer , it 'll help you also for the tab change trigger :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  'disabled' att to your html and on click event change att :
(You need jquery)

```
     <script>
     $('your eldmdnt name or id or class').attr('disabled','disabeld');
    </script>
```

Use disabled att and don't use active when whant be active remove this att when want be unactive insert this att(code is for make disabled)

Hope it will work.let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/queryj/CnEUh/1/), it shows how to add active class to the jQuery UI tabs

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Content for Tab 1</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Content for Tab 2</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
</div>
```

Your jQuery

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
activate: function (event, ui) {
    var active = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
    $("#tabid").html('the tab id is ' + $("#tabs ul>li a").eq(active).attr("href"));

}});
```

Your CSS

```
#tabs {
width: 95%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 10px;}
```

Comment: The problem is that the menu and the tabs are not wrapped within the same div #tabs.

Comment: this.parentElement().getAttribute('id');
Wrap this within braces and below this line, use 
var active = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $anchors = $('.menu-link'),
  $items = $('.nav-link');

$anchors.on('click', function() {
  var href = $(this).attr("href");

  $anchors.removeClass('active');
  $items.parent().removeClass('active');

  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.nav-link[href=' + href + ']').closest('li').addClass('active');

});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
  <li><a class="menu-link" href="#day">Day</a></li>
  <li><a class="menu-link" href="#night">Night</a></li>
  <li><a class="menu-link" href="#drinks">Joogid</a></li>
  <li><a class="menu-link" href="#takeaway">Takeaway</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#day" role="tab">DAY</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#night" role="tab">NIGHT</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#drinks" role="tab">JOOGID<br></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#takeaway" role="tab">takeaway</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

1. Get the click href
2. Use attribute select to select the proper href

Answer (score 0):

i think this might do the job.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $anchors = $('.menu-link'),
    $items = $('.nav-link');

    $anchors.on('click', function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        $('.nav').find('.nav-item').removeClass('active');
        $('.nav').find('.nav-item[href="'+href+'"]').addClass('active');
    });
});
```